# PYQT5 dialog self.close() do not stop while

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I am new to python and pyqt.
I have a app with a mainwindow and a dialog (settings window). In the dialog class (loaded with uic.loadUi) I have a while loop to do some opencv image detection. When i call the dialog close the while loop still running. How can I stop it?
Thank you
This is a code extract, and is all in one file:

```
class UI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        
        #xxxxxx MORE CODE xxxxx
        uic.loadUi("BTS.ui", self)
        self.action_Open_Settings.triggered.connect(lambda: self.open_settings_window('BAS'))
        self.show()
        
    def open_settings_window(self, target):
    # Open Settings Window
    s_window = SettingsWindow(target)
    s_window.exec()
    

class SettingsWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, target):
        super(SettingsWindow,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('set.ui', self)
        # Settings Windows named SettingsWindow
        self.setWindowTitle(target)

        # Load Settings
        if target == 'BAS':
            self.H_MIN = B_H_MIN
            self.H_MAX = B_H_MAX
            self.S_MIN = B_S_MIN
            self.S_MAX = B_S_MAX
            self.Area_Value_Text.setEnabled(False)
            self.Peri_Value_Text.setEnabled(False)

        else:  
            self.H_MIN = R_H_MIN
            self.H_MAX = R_H_MAX
            

        self.show()
        self.run(target)

    def run(self, target):
        global gtarget
        global CROP_SIZE

        ref_image = "./set_ref.jpg"
        img = cv2.imread(ref_image)

        while True:
            print('running')

            frame = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 720))

            h_min = self.horizontalSlider_Hue_Min.value()
            h_max = self.horizontalSlider_Hue_Max.value()

            #********MORE CODE*************

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                SettingsWindow.close
                break


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    UIWindow = UI()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What exactly is going on in that `while True` and why does it need to be happening constantly?  You should probably be using Qt's event system to do whatever is going on in there.

Comment: Note that `SettingsWindow.close` doesn't do anything if you don't put the `()` in there to actually call the function -- but also, you probably need to call it on an *instance* of `SettingsWindow`, not the class.  The types of errors in this code suggest to me that you should back up and learn the Python basics before diving into a project this complex.  It's very difficult to learn this many different things at once, and it's hard to answer a question like this when there are so many different topics to cover at the same time.

Comment: I know is not perfect and I'm missing some basic infomation. But all the program works fine except this. The code in the while is a opencv code to find the HSV value with qt slider and a sample image. So I need a while loop.

Comment: That while loop shouldn't be run in the main thread, as it would potentially block the normal event loop (so, the window would "freeze" and won't respond to input events). You should use threading (possibly with QThread) and a basic bool flag instead of `True` for the while. Besides, your code has various issues (like the pointless `self.close()` in the close event) and code style/indentation problems.

Comment: this code completely violates the basic structure of a GUI program. your "run" method never returns, and you call it in the constructor of a dialog... just no. please work through some Qt tutorials. you may write code in event handlers, e.g. the event handler for a slider being moved. in there you can do your processing _once_ and send the result to be displayed in an appropriate Qt widget. no while-true loops! **that loop is completely unnecessary.** you don't even need threads so don't even go there.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this make sense. Moved to valueChanged.connect event and all is perfect now. Thank you!